# Python/Pandas - ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df:

        A      B 
id
 3   'Yes'    23
 5   'Yes'    67
 6    'No'    56
 8    'No'    23
```

I have another dataframe:

```
calc:
       A    B
id   
 3   'No'   4
```

I would like to update df with calc values. I'm trying to use the following:

```
tgsm.loc[i]=calc
```

However, that doesn't work. I keep getting the following error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 693, in _align_series
raise ValueError('Incompatible indexer with Series')
ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series
```

If  try `tgsm.loc[i]=calc[i]`, it gets me to this other error:

```
File "pandas/index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)
File "pandas/index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)
File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12368)
File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: 3
```

Can anyone help enlightening my journey?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) method to directly overwrite it in place.

```
df.update(calc)
```

Comment: does this work only because they both share the same index? Is there a more generalized solution so long as the element counts agree between both sides of the `loc` assignment?